# jqPlot : Rotate xaxis date labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm trying to rotate dates on my xaxis. It seems that the `rotate` parameter isn't taken into account, while `fontFamily`, `fontSize` and `formatString` work.

I'm using jqPlot 1.0.8 with jQuery 1.10.2 and Firefox 23.0.1

http://jsfiddle.net/JVY6a/

HTML :

```
<div id="chart-blood-pressure" class="jqplot-target" data-json="{&quot;diastolic_blood_pressure&quot;:[[&quot;2013\/09\/25 00:00:00&quot;,100],[&quot;2013\/09\/24 00:00:00&quot;,70]],&quot;systolic_blood_pressure&quot;:[[&quot;2013\/09\/25 00:00:00&quot;,130],[&quot;2013\/09\/24 00:00:00&quot;,120]],&quot;heart_rate&quot;:[[&quot;2013\/09\/25 00:00:00&quot;,76],[&quot;2013\/09\/24 00:00:00&quot;,85]]}"></div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $('#chart-blood-pressure').data('json');
    var plot = $.jqplot('chart-blood-pressure', [data.diastolic_blood_pressure, data.systolic_blood_pressure, data.heart_rate], {
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                rendererOptions:{
                    tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
                },
                tickInterval:'1 day',
                tickOptions:{
                    fontSize:'10pt',
                    fontFamily:'Tahoma',
                    angle:-40,
                    formatString:'%b %#d, %Y',
                }
            },
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include canvasAxisTickRenderer plugin : [external link here](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js) or from jqPlot source ("/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js")

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>  
//or
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JVY6a/1/)

Comment: Thank you !! It's a mess with all theses plugins needed

Comment: Yes it is!! Examples on jqPlot documentation can gives you a nice view of which plugins you need for particular issues.

Comment: In fact some examples pages are incomplete and do not give every plugins needed... For example http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/rotatedTickLabelsZoom.html :)

Comment: You're right. My previous comment is so limited to examples from [http://www.jqplot.com/tests/](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/) and not [http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/) :)